How to convert image to EPL code correctly?
Hi i want to parse image to EPL code to print it on Zebra thermal printer using C#
This is epl output i got from simplest image of text in white background
N
GW0,0,34,1,00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
GW0,1,34,1,00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
GW0,2,34,1,00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
GW0,3,34,1,00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
GW0,4,34,1,00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
GW0,5,34,1,00000180000000000000000000000007000000000000000000000000004030000000
GW0,6,34,1,03E001800038C000000000000007C007000000000000000000000463004030000000
GW0,7,34,1,06300180003CC0000000000000066004000000000000000000000662000030180000
GW0,8,34,1,0633CF9E3C3CC79800000000000663CF38F3C7C38F100000000006763CCFFF3CC000
GW0,9,34,1,0413999B3836CD98000000000006C6CE6CF766E61F900000000006F66CCDBB188000
GW0,10,34,1,041319BF3037CCC0000000000007C7E4FCC7E6641F800000000003967ECDB1180000
GW0,11,34,1,063319B83033CCC0000000000006C604E0C706641C0000000000039C70CF31180000
GW0,12,34,1,077319983033CD98000000000006660460C70666181000000000039C60CE31188000
GW0,13,34,1,03E30F9F3031C79800000000000663C43CC3C6638F3000000000039C3CCFB11CC000
GW0,14,34,1,000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000018C0000000
GW0,15,34,1,00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001980000000
GW0,16,34,1,00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000F00000000
GW0,17,34,1,00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
GW0,18,34,1,00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
GW0,19,34,1,00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
GW0,20,34,1,00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
GW0,21,34,1,00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
GW0,22,34,1,00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
GW0,23,34,1,00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
GW0,24,34,1,00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
GW0,25,34,1,00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
GW0,26,34,1,00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
GW0,27,34,1,00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
GW0,28,34,1,0081818180000000000000000003C070021F030303020000000000401F1040E00000
GW0,29,34,1,01C7E7E7E0000000000000000007F1FC073F1F070F070000000001C03F18C3F00000
GW0,30,34,1,07C666627000000000000000000773CE0F301807181F0000000003C0381987100000
GW0,31,34,1,07C666303000000000000000000633861F30300F381F0000000003C0301B06000000
GW0,32,34,1,00C3E631E000000000000000000633071F3E3F1B3F030000000000C03E1F0E000000
GW0,33,34,1,00C3C7F3E0000000000000000007F307333F3F933F830000000000C03F1F0C780000
GW0,34,34,1,00C763F070000000000000000007E3076703B1B331830000000000C0039F0C780000
GW0,35,34,1,00C630303000000000000000000603067F83B1BFB1830000000000C0039B8E380000
GW0,36,34,1,00C6706070000000000000000006038E1F03338FB9830000000000C20399C7380000
GW0,37,34,1,00C7E7C7E000000000000000000601FC033F1F031F830000000000C73F18C3F80000
GW0,38,34,1,00C3C383C00000000000000000060078023C0E030E030000000000C21E18E1F00000
GW0,39,34,1,00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
GW0,40,34,1,00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
GW0,41,34,1,00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
GW0,42,34,1,00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
GW0,43,34,1,00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
GW0,44,34,1,00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
GW0,45,34,1,00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
GW0,46,34,1,00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
GW0,47,34,1,00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
GW0,48,34,1,00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
GW0,49,34,1,00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
GW0,50,34,1,00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
P1

The problem is that my epl code looks like bunch of stripes and dots than regular text on white black background. can I do this by GW command in EPL? Why 0 is presented as dots not as blank space. I test my ple on https://eplprinter.azurewebsites.net. Help pls :D
On lef i got my rendered epl on right i got original png image
Can i handle render image in pretty quialty using epl?

Update! I solved it. The problem was encoding the last parameter. It can't be formatted as ASCII, it has to be binary, so you have to generate it in an epl file and then test it :D
There is a helpful link for anyone who will have the same problem in the future, you can handle it :D
https://web.archive.org/web/20141109172303/http://nicholas.piasecki.name/blog/2013/02/using-the-epl2-gw-command/
